# Organizing code repositories for a Airflow cloud deployment

Tags: git, kubernetes, airflow, repo

**For a production Airflow Kubernetes deployment, what would be the recommended code repositories? Should DAG definition and DAG business logic be split into separate repos?**

I'm guessing that it's best practice to separate the DAG configuration, DAG business logic/dependencies, and Airflow container. Consequently, I'm envisioning the following:

- A repo containing the Airflow Docker image
- A repo containing the Airflow DAG definitions
- A repo containing the Airflow DAG Tasks (business logic)

In this setup the Airflow DAGs would be git-synced onto the pod or accessible via a PVC. The actual business logic for each task in that workflow would be in a separate repo that contains a Dockerfile. That repo would get spun up as a side-car container on the worker pod that the individual DAG tasks would then make entry-point/executable calls to.

I'm curious how other devs are structuring their repos to be well suited for deploying Airflow on the cloud.

Comment: Following because I'm interested in this too. So far, we've got a setup where it's one repo with all DAGs and all Docker image source code directories for DAGs that involve using Docker images for the logic (instead of inline in the DAG).

Comment: It feels really heavy, we don't like not being able to have a simple way of seeing one DAG at a time. We've decided we want to split it up into one GitHub repo per DAG (with its optional Docker image source code directory in the repo alongside the DAG) with a single CI/CD step to build the Docker image (if needed), template the image tag into the DAG, then sync the DAG with the Airflow's GCS bucket (we use Cloud Composer). Curious to see if other people talk about doing a similar thing.